# Android read custom file extension attachment

Tags: android, email, mime-types, android-contentresolver

I can open my custom file extension successfully. My problem is in reading the content from Gmail. I spent several hours trying to figure out this issue and there must be something obvious I'm missing.

I have file with an application specific extension ".myextension" and the  following in the AndroidManifest for the application. This part works.

```
<intent-filter
            android:icon="@drawable/my_launcher_icon">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension"
                />
            <data
                android:mimeType="application/myextension"
                android:host="*"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\. myextension"
                />
        </intent-filter>
```

I attempt to read the Uri with this code:

```
        Uri data = intent.getData();
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }

            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(data);
            if (is == null) return;

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int i;
            try {
                i = is.read();
                while (i != -1)
                {
                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
                    i = is.read();
                }
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String serverURL = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
            is.close();
```

The xxx.myextension file is a one-line text file that I email to the user.

When I tap on an email attachment in the Gmail client my activity receives the following (extracted from the intent data):

"content://com.google.android.gm.email.attachmentprovider/1/22/RAW"
mime type is: "typ=application/myextension"

When I attempt to read it I just get binary (seemingly) gibberish data.

When I tap on the same attachment using BlueMail my activity receives:

"content://me.bluemail.mail.attachmentprovider/44ce7126-f7f7-46d9-9b6e-41fb391a8de6/10e6c7e0-a0d0-40cc-925e-ef8a5cc3ee72/VIEW"
and the mime type is "typ=application/octet-stream"

I can read the string correctly in this case.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you compare the amount of bytes read with file size? Try some more apps.

Comment: Yes, the file size did not match my input file. I also sent the same file with a .txt extension and attempted to open it on a text editor from Gmail. The text editor could not read it.

Comment: Did not match? Smaller bigger? Please give exact sizes. So the text editor showed nothing? Wordpad on PC will show it. What do you see?

Comment: The read byte[] has 23 bytes. The original string in file has 78. I also read an 80 character string which resulted in a byte[] of 3 bytes. I know exactly what my file contains. The issue is opening it as a Gmail attachment in my phone's Gmail. I can open it with other mail programs on my Nexus phone.